# How to show when device is connected or disconnected in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api, domoticz

I am currently using domotz to shows when a device is connected. I currently in cell 4 show a green check mark for connectivity, how would I for cell 4 put an x mark for when it is disconnected because right now it does not separate weather it is connected or disconnected and shows. green mark for every device even devices that are not connected. Thanks

`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>  

<table id="devicelist" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>Display Name</th>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Model</th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var headers = {


success: function(data) {
var str = JSON.stringify(data);
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
var NumDevices = obj.length;
var table = document.getElementById('devicelist');

var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
cell1.innerHTML = i+1
cell2.innerHTML = obj[i].display_name;
cell3.innerHTML = obj[i].id;
cell4.innerHTML = "<img src='img/greenn.jpg'/>";

</script>
</body>
</html>
```